# Click Button to Open Another Applet

Tags: java, applet

I want to call another applet by clicking a button; the old applet will then be closed or reloaded to the new applet.

My Action Listener doesn't have anything  yet.

```
public class ConImage extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    Button btn;
    Applet second;

    public void init()
    {
        setSize(1600,900);
        setLayout(null);
        btn=new Button("Replace with other applet");

        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        btn.setLocation(100, 100);
        btn.setSize(100, 50);            
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   second=null;
        second= getAppletContext().getApplet("SecondClass");
        if (second!=null)
        {
            if(e.getSource()==Time)
            {
                SecondClass ma= (SecondClass) second;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't start variable names with capitals

Comment: And I don't think this is possible because of Java's security functions.

Comment: Use a CardLayout to switch between views

Comment: I've removed all the incidental details that only occlude the point of your question.

Comment: Thanks guys for the Suggestions Will Try my Best to Improve at this. I'm just new at this and I'm just learning through tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible because of Java's security system. The best way to so it is to have a master class, which has an array of `JApplet`. On that master applet I would create a method that sets the visible applet from the array, calls `init()` and when a render is requested call `paint()` of that applet.

Like so:

```
public class MasterApplet extends JApplet {

private int index = 0;
private JApplet[] applets;

public void init(){
    JApplet appletA = new AppletA();
    JApplet appletB = new AppletB();
    applets = new JApplet[]{appletA, appletB};
    setViewing(index);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    applets[index].paint(g);
}

public void setViewing(int idex){
    index = idex;
    applets[idex].init();
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Pretty much if you want to change the applet add it to the array of applets, and then call `setViewing()` with the index of that applet.

Comment: Or just use a CardLayout...also, how are you getting the current view attached to the native peer within the container of the browser....